# Setting up fixed effect regression with specific baseline comparison group

Tags: stata, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I'd like to set up a fixed effects regression equation where the coefficients and standard errors can be interpreted to represent a specific comparison that I am interested in. That is, I want to select a specific baseline group. I thought this would be simple but for some reason I am having trouble with it. I am using Stata.

I have the following type of data (see below) where each person is assigned to either group **T1 T2** or **C** (mutually exclusive). They also belong to some category **d1** **d2** or **d3** (mutually exclusive). There is a **post** variable which is 0 in the pre-period and 1 in the post-period. Note, the **T1**, **T2**, **C** and **d1-d3** variables do not change as values of **post** changes. Only the **Y** variable, which is the outcome of interest, changes with **post**. All the variables are binary.

[image]

What I want to do is analyze the impact of T on Y *within* each d block keeping C as the baseline group. So for example, I want to see the difference in Y for T1 in block d1 compared to Y for C in block d1, and whether this difference is statistically significant. Similarly, I want to also see the difference in Y for T2 in block d1 compared to Y for C in block d1, and whether the difference is statistically significant. And the same for blocks d2 and d3. Therefore, I want the baseline group to always be C in each d block. And I want to be mindful of the fixed effects nature of my data because there are two observations per person (id), driven mainly by different Y values for post=0 and post=1.

Should I be looking to set up something like this?

> Y = $\alpha$ + $\beta_1$ post*T1*d1 + $\beta_2$ post*T2*d1 + $\beta_3$ post*T1*d2 + $\beta_4$ post*T2*d2 + $\beta_5$ post*T1*d3 + $\beta_5$ post*T2*d3 + $\gamma_1$ post*C*d1 + $\gamma_2$ post*C*d2 + $\gamma_3$ post*C*d3

Where $\alpha$ is the fixed effect constant, and $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $\gamma_3$ tell me the value of Y for group C in different d buckets, and all the $\beta $ coefficients tell me the difference in Y value for the T1 and T2 groups compared to C within each d bucket. And, importantly, their standard errors also correspond to the specific difference with C.

I do not want a coefficient on post or the T1 and T2 variables separately, so in a normal linear regression, I would have tried for a noconstant option so that my baseline group was exactly what I omitted.

What would be your suggested Stata code for what I'm describing? You can ignore the fact that it's a binary dependent variable for the time being and just give me simple linear regression with fixed effects suggestions.

Comment: Since DID is just difference of four means, you should be able to check that your specification returns back the right three DIDs.

Comment: thanks @DimitriyV.Masterov. Do you mean I should just mechanically take the means of Y in each d block for the different T1 T2 and C groups, look at the difference between the T groups and C, and then see if my regression coeffs are calculating the same thing? I checked this and it didn't work out, which is why I am asking for help with how to specify my regression.

Comment: I believe you would need to calculate the full difference in differences : $ (\bar Y^{Post}_{T,d=k} - \bar Y^{Pre}_{T,d=k})-(\bar Y^{Post}_{C,d=k} - \bar Y^{Pre}_{C,d=k})$ for $k=1,2,3$.

Comment: If that does not match, show us your Stata actual code.